# Redis in rails, backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, redis

Im learning Redis and trying it to run with rails and backbone. I need to GET/SET 50 values every 66ms on my front-end. I need to have objects (@monsters) with redis and i did them this way. I dont really know or its becouse my computer slow or code weak, or backbone's beginners code is slowing my calculations, but after 3 seconds all PUT/GET to database pending and everything working slower and slower. I'm debugging with localhost, maybe when i push to heroku it is fast enough to update all data becouse of heroku servers? or not? 
How could i improve the dataSET/dataGET?

My random Redis key and value in console looks like:

```
2.1.2 :002 > $redis.get('1001')
 => "[452,305,452,316,3]"
# (X position, Y position, Targets X position, Targets Y position, Level)
```

i have 50 keys named from '1001' to 1050' with values of each monster Xpos, Ypos, XposDest, YposDest positions which gonna be on canvas map. These are parsed to objects with Rails and fetched to backbone.

```
# Getting all values from Redis database and sending to backbone.
class MainController < ApplicationController

  def index         
    m = []
    for key in $redis.keys do
      value = JSON.parse($redis.get(key))
      m.push id: key.to_i, 
             Xpos: value[0], 
             Ypos: value[1],
             XposDest: value[2],
             YposDest: value[3],
             level: value[4]
    end
    @monsters = m
  end



# Getting all values from Backbone and updating Redis database.
class MonstersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    id = monster_params[:id]  
    xpos = monster_params[:Xpos] 
    ypos = monster_params[:Ypos] 
    xposDest = monster_params[:XposDest] 
    yposDest = monster_params[:YposDest] 
    level = monster_params[:level]
    $redis.set id, [xpos,ypos,xposDest,yposDest,level].to_json
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html do
           render nothing: true
       end   
     end
  end
  private
    def monster_params
      params.require(:monster)
    end
end
```

here goes my backbone important part

```
Sprint.Views.Maps ||= {}
class Sprint.Views.Maps.IndexView extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->
    if move_on_count is 0
      @addAll()
      @game_init_function()

  mob_x_post = []
  mob_y_post = []
  mob_x_posdest = []
  mob_y_posdest = [] 
  move_on_count = 0

  game_init_function: ->
    @receiving_attributes_from_database()
    @move_on()

  move_on: ->
    move_on_count++
    self = this
    timer 66, ()-> self.fetch_mobs_from_redis_db()

  fetch_mobs_from_redis_db: ->
    self = this
    @addAll
    @save_mobs_position()
    @receiving_attributes_from_database()

  addAll: () =>
    @options.monsters.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (monster) =>
    monstersas.push monster
    mobbys.push monster.attributes.level

  save_mobs_position: ->
    for alfa in [0..(monstersas.length-1)]
      @options.monsters.models[alfa].save((level: alfa+1, YposDest: parseInt(mob_y_posdest[alfa]), XposDest: parseInt(mob_x_posdest[alfa]), Ypos: parseInt(mob_y_post[alfa]), Xpos: parseInt(mob_x_post[alfa])))

  receiving_attributes_from_database: ->
    for cnt in [0..(monstersas.length-1)]
      mob_y_post[cnt] = monstersas[cnt].attributes.Ypos
      mob_x_post[cnt] = monstersas[cnt].attributes.Xpos
      mob_y_posdest[cnt] = monstersas[cnt].attributes.YposDest
      mob_x_posdest[cnt] = monstersas[cnt].attributes.XposDest 


# here goes big canvas code..
```

Im still learning rails, backbone, coffeescript, redis.. Here i believe are so many things that could make my game running slow..

Comment: Three seconds seems like way too long. However, it's impossible to tell you how to fix it without knowing where the slowdown is. If you've already figured this out, it's unclear from your question. Can you please update your question on what part of the process is taking a long time? Consult the Rails server log and your browser's Developer Tools to see how long the server-side and client-side operations are taking, respectively.

Comment: By the way, your client-side code needs to be built with the assumption that, because of latency, round-trips may be way longer than 66ms, regardless of how long the server takes to respond or how long the client takes to process the response. You're sending 15 requests/sec.—what happens if none of them returns for 1,000ms, and then they all return at once? You'll want to make sure your tests include scenarios like this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will reduce this to 1000ms. Maybe you know how i can make this "SET" function not as Client-side, but as Server-side calculation every 1000ms? I want actually SET all mob positions only at server-side, and each Player would only GET them every 1000ms. So it would be less CPU. I just odnt know how to make server-side real-time functions, have no idea..

Comment: That's a really big question that's beyond the scope of a comment. The best answer I can give you is, take a look at [the abundance of information Google can provide](https://www.google.com/search?q=realtime+apps+with+rails&es_sm=91&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2013%2Ccd_max%3A&tbm=).